# Can't a mother board with thunderbolt 3 do what an external GPU enclosure does

Tags: pci-express, thunderbolt

External GPU enclosures are now available in the market to which we can connect our laptop via Thunderbolt 3 interface to expand our graphics processing.

If we already have a motherboard with Thunderbolt 3 interface. Is it possible to utilize it as an external GPU adapter, given the required drivers are already developed?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Apple had a target display mode, which allowed a mac with a display port or thunderbolt port to work as external gpu/display for another mac. This has not been widely copied. There is nothing preventing a second computer to act as a external gpu other than programming time/development.